# Split in javascript without tags with specific text

Tags: javascript, regex

im trying to split a string

```
<div id = 'tostart'><button>todo </button>hometown todo </div>
```

with "to" as a keyword.

the problem is i do not have to split in between the tags and have to only split from outside the tags so if i split i get a result like

```
    arr = ["<div id = 'tostart'><button>","do","</button>home","wn ","do </div>"]
```

is there a regex by using which it can be acheived.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regex is not going to be your friend here. You will need to parse it yourself and decide on your own rules as to what qualifies as being within a tag or not

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do. Dismiss the idea that you should solve it with Regex. Now...

Comment: i acheived this with a basic regex for splitting it with a space excluding the tags which was `var splitText = text.match(/[\<].+?[\>]+|[^\s]+/g);` but this splits from spaces and i need to split with a word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am relying on your HTML using `&lt;` and `&gt;` to escape stray `<` `>` that browsers tolerate but validators don't!

```
str.split(/to(?=[^>]*(?=<|$))/g);
```

As others have said, regex isn't going to work for really messy HTML (e.g. inline script elements).

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
var str = "<div id = 'tostart'><button>todo </button>hometown todo </div>";
var res = str.replace(/to/g, '|').replace(/(.*?)(<.*?)\|(.*?>)/g, '$1$2to$3');
console.log(res.split("\|"));
```

output :

```
["<div id = 'tostart'><button>", "do </button>home", "wn ", "do </div>"]
```

@musefan:

This is actually done as an improvisation .

first I replaced all the `to` with `|` and then I selected all the pipes which were inside the `<` or `>` and replaced them with `to`. Finally I could split on the basis of the `|` which were left over by the previous replace.

regex : `(.*?)(<.*?)\|(.*?>)`

will select all `|` characters which are inside `<` and `>`

Comment: Very nice! Wish I understood what that regex is doing though!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very quick and dirty function that will do what you want. Note that there is probably a more efficient way to do this, and also that it does not cater for any `>` characters that might be part of an attribute value. However, it does work for your example input:

```
function splitNonTag(input, splitText) {
    var inTag = false;//flag to check if we are in a tag or not
    var result = [];//array for storing results
    var temp = "";//string to store current result

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var c = input[i];//get the current character to process

        //check if we are not in a tag and have found a split match
        if (!inTag && input.substring(i).indexOf(splitText) == 0) {
            result.push(temp);//add the split data to the results
            temp = "";//clear the buffer ready for next set of split data
            i += splitText.length - 1;//skip to the end of the split delimiter as we don't keep this data
            continue;//continue directly to next iteration of for loop
        }

        temp += c;//append current character to buffer as this is part of the split data

        //check if we are entering, or exiting a tag and set the flag as needed
        if (c == '<') inTag = true;
        else if (c == '>') inTag = false;
    }
    //if we have any left over buffer data then this should become the last split result item
    if (temp) 
        result.push(temp);

    return result;
}
var input = "<div id = 'tostart'><button>todo </button>hometown todo </div>";
var result = splitNonTag(input, 'to');
console.log(result);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/JnpMc/)

Comment: this leaves the ending div for the string but a really good function

Comment: @BackStabber: Sorry, bit of a typo, fixed now